# Bootstrap grid system: column classes without a number

Tags: css, bootstrap-grid

Why can I use bootstrap col classes without the number of cols and how is this interpreted? E.g. in the snippet

```
<div class="row row-header">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm align-self-center">
  </div>
</div>
```

the second inner div uses col classes that corresponding dimensionally to the col classes of the first inner div. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge `col` class has been introduced in Bootstrap 4. This class works because Bootstrap 4 uses `display:flex` to layout content rather than the classic `float:left`. With flexbox you don't have to explicitly define width for each column. If a `.row` contains two `col`s, the `col`s occupy 50% of the width of `.row`, if three `col`s then 33.3333% width and so on. Check out this excellent article on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to know about flexbox in detail.